# Fatal error Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php, java, mysql, mysqli, string

necesito ayuda, ya revise millones de veces pero no encuentro el error siguiente

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ellas\modulos\php_conexion.php:10 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Ellas\index.php(3): include_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ellas\modulos\php_conexion.php on line 10

```js
<?php
    #error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
    $servidor='localhost';                                      //
    $usuario='root';                                            //
    $pass='';                                                   // Nos conectamos a
    $bd='bdtiendita';
        

    $conexion = mysqli_connect("$servidor","$usuario","$pass");
    mysqli_select_db("$bd","$conexion"); 
             date_default_timezone_set("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"); 
    mysqli_query("SET NAMES utf-3");
    mysqli_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf");
    $s='$';
    
    function limpiar($tags){
        $tags = strip_tags($tags);
        return $tags;
    }

    $conexion = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $pass, $bd);    //
    $conexion->set_charset('utf-3'); // Los datos vendran en formato utf-8
    
    $base_url="http://127.1.1.0/EMANUEL/agenda/"; // Url donde estara el proyecto

    
?>
```

*estoy usando xampp

Answer (score 0):

Te aconsejo que prestes atención a tu código, hay varios errores muy básicos:

1. Estás usando variables/objetos como cadenas al encerrarlas entre comillas. Aquí: `mysqli_select_db("$bd","$conexion");` **`$conexion`** sería tu objeto conexión, pero al ponerlo entre comillas PHP interpreta que quieres tratarlo como una cadena, de ahí el error: *`Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string`*
2. Además la función `mysqli_select_db` **no es necesaria en este contexto**, tú puedes indicar la base de datos en el cuarto parámetro de la conexión, como de hecho ya haces (cuando usas `new mysqli()`).
3. Estás conectado **dos veces**, con el estilo procedural y con el estilo orientado a objetos
4. Estás usando una codificaciín que no existe: `utf-3`

Tu código debería funcionar así, salvo otros errores (he preferido el estilo orientado a objetos, porque es más claro y más moderno):

```
<?php
    #error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
    $servidor='localhost';                                      //
    $usuario='root';                                            //
    $pass='';                                                   // Nos conectamos a
    $bd='bdtiendita';
        
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"); 

    $conexion = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $pass, $bd);    //
    $conexion->set_charset('utf-8'); // Los datos vendran en formato utf-8
    
    $base_url="http://127.1.1.0/EMANUEL/agenda/"; // Url donde estara el proyecto

    /*
       No sé para que es esto, aquí te lo dejo
    */
    function limpiar($tags){
        $tags = strip_tags($tags);
        return $tags;
    }
```